# What does "enum class" mean in Visual C++ 2012?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++, enums, c++11

There are two conflicting definitions of `enum class` in Visual C++ 2012:

- The C++11, type-safe version of `enum`
- The C++/CLI, `System::Enum` derived type, equivalent to a `ref class` with static const integral members.

Does the meaning of `enum class` change when you enable or disable the /clr switch?

Comment: The name is is Visual C++ 2012.  It is _version_ 11 of the product (version 17 of the compiler!), but the product _name_ is Visual C++ 2012 (and it is part of Visual Studio 2012).

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Visual C++ 11 is how Microsoft usually refers to it (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx) (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852594.aspx) (http://herbsutter.com/2012/02/29/vc11-beta-on-feb-29/). Apparently the official naming is "Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2012". Anyway I won't argue anymore about this.

Comment: Yes, all of the preview releases used "11."  When the final release was produced it was branded "2012."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A managed enumeration must have an access specifier (either `public` or `private`).  A C++11 scoped enumeration must not have an access specifier.  For example,

```
enum class E { e0 };

public enum class F { f0 };
private enum class G { g0 };
```

`E` is valid in C++, C++/CLI, and C++/CX, and it is an ordinary C++ scoped enumeration.

`F` and `G` are valid only in C++/CLI and C++/CX, and they name a managed enumeration (in C++/CLI) or a Windows Runtime enumeration (in C++/CX).